# PHP header() Can not open xlsx file after download

Tags: php

I use header() to download an xlsx file from given url. The file is downloaded but I can't not open it. It shows error
[image]

Below is my code

```
$url = "http://example.com/attachment/file.xlsx"
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Test.xlsx');
readfile($url);
exit();
```

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Test.xlsx"'); I'm not sure....

Answer (score 2):

Randy, your question looks weird. The URL in the serve response is way different than the one in your code.

Before commencing the download - sending the headers, do a is_file() or other check on the URL and only start the download if the file exists.

I suspect you are trying fopen on URL, not local file and the URL may be either incorrect or on server not allowing fopen on URLs.

Sample:

```
  $url = "http://example.com/attachment/file.xlsx";
  if (!fopen($url,'r')) exit('File/URL not accessible'); 
  else fclose($url);
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Test.xlsx');
  readfile($url);
  exit();
```

Comment: You should provide some code or example to help him to understand your answer. For me, this is a comments.... not an answer.